# How to set the tab active based on the value choosed from the button click

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I need to set the tabs active based on the value choosed while clicking the button.

Find the code below :

```
<a href="smeHosting#linuxHosting" class="btn btn-primary">Linux Shared hosting @ Rs.62 / mo</a>
<a  href="smeHosting#windowsHosting"  class="btn btn-primary">Windows Shared hosting @ Rs.62 / mo</a>
```

Find the js:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

$('ul.smeHostingTabsContainer li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.smeHostingTabsContainer li').removeClass('active');
    $('.tabContent').removeClass('active');
    $('.tabHostingFeatureContainer section').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('active');
    $(".tabHostingFeatureContainer section#" + tab_id).addClass('active');

})

});
```

I have used the above js for the page called sme hosting and it works correctly, but while i click the link from the index page i need to set the tabs in sme hosting page as active based on the link clicked.

Help me to set the tabs active based on the values from the button.

Comment: you want to submit the form and on redirect back the tab which was active previously be enabled?

Comment: read the header of the request and find which OS is requesting your server.

Comment: I have two anchor links in the same page and while clicking the link, I need to set the tab from another page as active.

Comment: why do you do it with PHP ? use javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flash session variable in your controller function which opens your second page after button click.

```
session()->flash('tabName', 'active');
```

Now in the second page get the session variable.

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link {{Session::get('tabName','')}}" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab" >Your Tab

   </a>
</li>
```

**Session::get('tabName','')** will return active if the session is set otherwise empty.

And if you are on the same page you can use jquery, add an extra class to your buttons

```
<a href="smeHosting#linuxHosting" class="btnTab btn btn-primary">Linux Shared hosting @ Rs.62 / mo</a>
<a  href="smeHosting#windowsHosting"  class="btnTab btn btn-primary">Windows Shared hosting @ Rs.62 / mo</a>
```

Now in in jquery check the button which button is clicked

```
$('.btnTab').on('click', function (e) {

      var button= $(e.target).attr("href");

   if(button==="smeHosting#linuxHosting"){
       //do something its hosting button click
    }
 else{
  //its another button
  }
 });
```

Comment: I have not used controllers for the index page, how can i pass the session data from index page  to the sme hosting  page

Comment: when you click on button, is there any controller event fires? please share the code of the function which opens your second page

Comment: if no back end code runs on button click then you can send ajax call to set session variable on button click.